# Using Parse for Facebook login but i get --https://api.parse.com/1/users 404-- After Refreshing 3 Times

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, authentication, parse-platform

I Used the instructions here: https://parse.com/docs/js_guide#fbusers (Facebook login using Javascript) to write a login page that uses Facebook authentication.

When I first login, all works perfect (Except a 'FB.init has already been called' warning in the console.)

When I Refresh the page, I see a "FB.login() Called when user is already connected" Error in the console. But I still get a "User logged in through Facebook" message as expected.

If I hit refresh Again, I now get a message box saying "User cancelled the facebook login or did not fully authorize" (Msgbox is defined in the code),
and in the console I now see that the POST to https://api.parse.com/1/users returned a 400 Error, as opposed to before in which i got a 200 OK.

This is my HTML Code:

```
<html><head></head><body> <div id="fb-root"></div> 
<script src="http://www.parsecdn.com/js/parse-1.2.9.min.js"></script>
<script>Parse.initialize("<key>", "<key>"); // Additional JS functions here 

window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
   Parse.FacebookUtils.init({
   appId      : '<id>', // App ID
   channelUrl : '<path>/Channel.html', // Channel File
   status     : true, // check login status
   cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
   xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
 });

 Parse.FacebookUtils.logIn(null, {
     success: function(user) {
     if (!user.existed()) {
        alert("User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
     } else {
        alert("User logged in through Facebook!");
     }
     },
        error: function(user, error) {
          alert("User cancelled the Facebook login or did not fully authorize.");
     }
  });
}; 

// Load the SDK asynchronously 
(function(d, s, id){
   var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk')); 
</script> 
<fb:login-button show-faces="true"    width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
</body> </html>
```

I would appreciate it if anyone could spot the problem.
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

"User cancelled the facebook login or did not fully authorize" means that you are already logged in. Use chrome's developer tools console to check if your current user using this commmand:

```
Parse.User.current()
```

If you get an object, you are already logged in.

You can use `Parse.User.logOut()` to logout, then `Parse.User.current()` should return a null!

Also you can use `Parse.User.current().get('authData')['facebook']`, as [mentioned here](https://parse.com/questions/javascript-parseuserlogout-logs-out-from-facebook)

Notes:
If logging out from parse logs you out of facebook, [update your parse reference](https://www.parse.com/questions/facebook-session-terminated-with-javascripts-parseuserlogout)